# Mathematical equality of two SQL statements

Tags: database-theory

Is there a way to get check the mathematical equality of two SQL statements?

I have two SQL statements:

- SQL_STATEMENT_1
- SQL_STATEMENT_2

Running both statements on data and comparing the output does not help at all.

The set maths behind the statements needs to be evaluated, like a equation solver does.

Out of scope of my question are things like:

- comparisons other then equality (greater than, less than, LIKE, ...)
- stored procedures, or triggers
- Common Table Expressions (WITH)

In the scope:

- Subselects: WHERE other_id IN (SELECT id FROM other WHERE ...)
- JOINS

Comment: A partial solution would be comparing the execution plans of 2 queries. If the execution plans are the same, then they are equal. However the relationship doesn't work both ways. There can be 2 logically equivalent queries that have different execution plans.

Comment: @BuahahaXD: that's not true. `select * from foo where id = 4` will most certainly have the same execution plan as `select * from foo where id = 2`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tested it on SQL Server and got 2 different XML files. The parameters were included as a <ParameterList> node in the XML file. Visually, these plans were identical (table scan + select). But I believe you might be right about comparing the execution plans.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is correct when it comes to unique keys. For all others, It is possible for `select * from foo  where id = 4` and `select * from foo where id = 2` to have two different execution plans if 1) the index stats are not up-to-date and 2) even if the index stats are up-to-date, the key distribution of id is lopsided (provided id is not a unique key).

Answer (score 8):

What is the mathematical equality of two SQL statements? For me two queries are equivalent if, when given both the same of any dataset, they return the same result set.

As you pointed out, SQL queries, a superset of [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra), can be very complex.  We can mix subqueries, use stored procedures and functions ([deterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm) or not) which will make you query looks more like *real code*.  If you are talking about these kinds of queries then it is going to be really hard.  In fact it is probably no different than the "are two algorithms equivalent" problem.

Under those conditions it is probably impossible.

**However...**

...it *might* be feasible if the two queries you want to compare are strict set operations.  If so, you can convert the queries to relational algebra and then work it out following [equivalence rules](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/32495/equivalenceRules.pdf).  If you have a selection/restriction with nontrivial boolean conditions then you might end up needing to prove than thoses conditions are also equivalent.  You'll then need to rely on [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) and you'll probably end up doing a [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).

As you can see this is going to be a lot of work and, as far as I know, nothing exists to compute all of that automatically.  Nevertheless, I found some tools that you might found useful if you want to tackle the task:

- [RelaX a relational algebra calculator](https://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/)
- [Truth table generator](http://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html)

Comment: My question only is about set operations. I updated the question. It is related to "are two algorithms equivalent" problem. But the context is limit, only the basic operations of sets, joins, subselects are in my scope.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to check semantic equivalence in finite time by definition, see [Rice's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem):

> for any non-trivial property of partial functions, there is no general and effective method to decide whether an algorithm computes a partial function with that property.

Comment: This is only just not a comment.  Can you expand on the applicability of Rice to this context, please.

Comment: Even if it were theoretically possible the current SQL standard syntax is so baroque it would be impossible in practice

Comment: With OP explanation it looks like the question is more about logical equivalence than semantical equivalence.  The real question is : can we convert SQL statements to a mathematical expression and then evaluate logical equivalence?

Answer (score 2):

dba user Lennart pointed me to this project:

http://cosette.cs.washington.edu/

> Cosette is an automated prover for checking equivalences of SQL queries. It formalizes a substantial fragment of SQL in the Coq Proof Assistant and the Rosette symbolic virtual machine. It returns either a formal proof of equivalance or a counterexample for a pair of given queries.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to build a parser, or better, use an existing one. I believe C# has a TSQLParser class and has a Parse() method.
The parser will break your query to sub-classes which you can then compare.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a Set Theory based equivalency test, your best bet is to convert any `WHERE` conditions that can be converted into a type of `JOIN` (inner or outer) and have the statement refactored.  This includes `IN subselect` and `EXISTS subselect` and any other conditions in the `WHERE` clause that contains the word `SELECT`. If you perform this on both SQL statements, you will have a new `FROM` clause which represents the set-based logic/math you are interested in.  Then you can just visually compare the two statements.  If you're looking for an automated way of doing all this, I don't know of a tool that can do exactly this.