# Subselect vs join: Are both SQL queries equal?

Tags: postgresql

I have this db:

```
DROP TABLE auth_user_groups;
DROP TABLE auth_user;
DROP TABLE auth_group;

CREATE TABLE auth_user (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    username character varying(150) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE auth_group (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name character varying(80) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE auth_user_groups (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id integer REFERENCES auth_user(id) NOT NULL,
    group_id integer REFERENCES auth_group(id) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_groups UNIQUE(user_id, group_id)
);

INSERT INTO auth_user VALUES (1, 'user1');
INSERT INTO auth_user VALUES (2, 'user2');
INSERT INTO auth_group VALUES (1, 'group1');
INSERT INTO auth_group VALUES (2, 'group2');
INSERT INTO auth_user_groups VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO auth_user_groups VALUES (2, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO auth_user_groups VALUES (3, 2, 2);
```

SQL statement using join:

```
select username from auth_user, auth_user_groups, auth_group where 
  auth_group.name='group1' and 
  auth_user_groups.group_id=auth_group.id and 
  auth_user.id=auth_user_groups.user_id;
```

SQL statement using subselect:

```
select username from auth_user where id in (
  select user_id from auth_user_groups where group_id in (
    select id from auth_group where name ='group1'));
```

Is the result of both SQL statements equal for all possible data sets?

I use PostgreSQL, but AFAIK this should not matter for this question.

Comment: Interesting question indeed. Proving equivalence between queries is, in general, a difficult task. Though it does not answer your question (AFAIK `IN` predicate is not supported) you might find some interest in cosette:  http://cosette.cs.washington.edu/

Comment: @Lennart Thank you for your feedback. Someone asked the general question about two sql statements being equal some month ago: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96865/mathematical-equality-of-two-sql-statements

Answer (score 1):

Both query will return same possible data sets as if you use `in` as sub query, it behaves like inner join in SQL query and where clause in both SQL statements should be same as in your `where condition`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both queries would return the same data.

You may want to use `EXISTS` to help your Query Optimizer, since you are only SELECTing data from 1 of the 3 tables.

It also helps readability if you keep your code short and well-formatted:

```
SELECT username
FROM auth_user u
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM auth_user_groups ug
        JOIN auth_group g ON g.id = ug.group_id
        WHERE g.name = 'group1'
            AND ug.user_id = u.id
        );
```